# Is it possible to get reviews made by a user on Facebook via Graph API / FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Despite all my research, I can't find a way to get this data via Graph API.

It seems that no permission matches with this...

[image: reviews data]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/ratings

Keep in mind that you need a Page Access Token for this, so you must be Admin of the Page. No extra permission needed, just `manage_pages` to get the Page Access Token, of course.

Getting the ratings for a specific User without accessing a Page is not possible afaik.

Comment: oh, that´s not possible at all, i´m afraid